# How do you get the absolute x/y position of an embedded element in a UIView?

Tags: ipad, layout

If you have UIView's embeded within other UIView's, when you get the .frame.origin.x value of a widget in the internal embedded view, it gives you the x/y value for the position in the internal view's coordinate system.

I want to get the x/y position of the element in the absolute coordinate system of the entire iPad visible area.  (Or with respect to the top-most view.)

Answer (score 6):

There are methods which can help you to convert frame.
[- (CGRect)convertRect:(CGRect)rect toView:(UIView *)view](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html)
[- (CGRect)convertRect:(CGRect)rect fromView:(UIView *)view](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html)

```
CGRect f = [someView convertRect:someView.bounds toView:window];
```